# Netbird (Wireguard) SSH Connections Blocked Even Though Ping Works

Tags: networking, macos, ssh, wireguard, netbird

I've begun using Netbird 0.24.3 as an easy way to implement a multi-site secure network via Wireguard. I have 7 peers and for the most part, it's been working great. Tonight, I was connected to a MacOS 13.x peer (rosalind.netbird.selfhosted) from another, MacOS 14 peer (falstaff.netbird.selfhosted) using SMB to transfer files. Midtransfer, everything froze up to the point I had to disconnect the Netbird client to unblock Finder (even going into terminal and trying to use `umount` to unmount the frozen resource caused a freeze).

Since that incident, "falstaff" cannot use SSH, VNC or SMB to "rosalind" (or vise versa). Both computers can connect to a third MacOS peer and also a Linux peer at a third location just fine via either the Netbird assigned hostname or Netbird assigned IP address.

Rosalind's network happens to be setup with a peer that is functioning as a Netbird network/egress route; if falstaff accesses rosalind via its local NATed IP address (192.168.4.250), it works. The problem only arises when I use the Netbird assigned IP address or the Netbird DNS name.

Both computers have their firewalls off, otherwise I'd think somehow they were mutually blocking certain ports from each other.

Both list their mutual connections (via `netbird status -d`) as direct P2P connections. For "falstaff" it says "ICE candidate (Local/Remote): host/host," while for "rosalind" it says "ICE candidate (Local/Remote): host/prflx."